# Performing specific operation on individual keys in dictionary with list values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary, and for each key in the dictionary, I have a list of lists of values. I want to edit all the values (every value in the list of lists) for each individual key. I am performing division based on the values in another dictionary with the same keys.

```
for key in new_vec:
    for jey in result_two:
        if key == jey:
            new_vec[key] = new_vec[key] / result_two[jey]
            #for list1 in new_vec[key]:
                #for number in list1:
                    #print(number)
                    #number = number / result_two[jey]
```

When I try the first solution, I get extremely small numbers, which makes me think that `result_two[jey]` is being continuously divided in each iteration of the for a loop. When I try the commented-out code, the values do not become modified at all for some reason.

the second dict will have each each key from the first dict and a different list of lists of values:

```
result_two = {'TC821P': 1790.0, 'TC821T': 458.0, 'TC864P': 210.0, 'TC864T': 434.0, 'TC877P': 967.0, 'TC877T': 350.0, 'TC916P': 949.0, 'TC916T': 588.0, 'TC920P': 597.0, 'TC920T': 366.0, 'TC928P': 1604.0, 'TC928T': 255.0, 'TC936P': 1165.0, 'TC936T': 791.0, 'TC943P': 1132.0, 'TC943T': 479.0, 'TC953P': 876.0, 'TC953T': 641.0, 'TC959P': 278.0, 'TC959T': 544.0, 'TC966P': 988.0, 'TC966T': 485.0, 'TC967P': 481.0, 'TC967T': 588.0, 'TC974P': 673.0, 'TC974T': 618.0, 'TC977P': 863.0, 'TC977T': 936.0, 'TC978P': 1087.0, 'TC978T': 580.0, 'TC979P': 709.0, 'TC979T': 1015.0}

new_vec = {'TC821P': [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 283.0, 68.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 59.0, 218.0, 85.0, 15.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 17.0, 90.0, 83.0, 41.0, 20.0, 64.0, 10.0, 0.0], [0.0, 43.0, 191.0, 119.0, 38.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 42.0, 159.0, 67.0, 11.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 4.0, 16.0, 13.0, 5.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]}
```

Comment: provide some sample data, thank you

Comment: You only want one loop in this situation, not two

Comment: Are the keys guaranteed to match up? What should happen if a key isn't in the second dict? (Error or skip the division?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the keys in the two dicts match:

```
for key in new_vec:
    new_vec[key] /= result_two[key]
```

If the keys don't necessarily match, and missing entries should be skipped:

```
for key in new_vec.keys() & result_two.keys():
    new_vec[key] /= result_two[key]
```

Comment: Ah, you've added sample data and new_vec is a list of lists; you'll have to adapt the solution for that. This will only work for single values or numpy arrays

Comment: Interesting, my data was originally in 2d numpy array before I flattened, I will see if this operation works on the original

Comment: Thanks this worked! I'm interested though why this works on a numpy array? Is the numpy array seen as a single object, which a list of lists is multiple objects?

Comment: Yeah, a numpy array is a single object, and has  operations like multiplication, division, addition etc defined in the mathematical way. A list is also a single object, but has multiplication and addition defined for a list of generic items, and no division or subtraction, so if you want the mathematical operations, you have to manually do them element-wise (probably with a list comprehension).